# Use Utopia greeks with unicode-math

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, greek, fourier

Is there a way to use `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` as the math font in a LaTeX document and substitute Utopia greeks? I knew how to get a mix of Palatino and Utopia with the `pdftex` engine by appropriately merging `mathpazo.sty` and `fourier.sty`, but I'm not sure if it's possible with `luatex` using the `unicode-math` package.

Comment: The greek letters in fourier are not from utopia but have been made for the fourier package. As they exist only in type 1 it is imho difficult to use them with unicode math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Greek alphabets from the `fourier` package (which, pedantically, are not part of the Utopia font donated by Adobe), technically the answer is yes.  However, you are more likely to want to use something like the [Linguistics Pro](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/linguistics-pro) font, a fork of Utopia that includes Greek letters similar to those from `fourier`:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % Upright Greek letters.

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{Greek,greek}]{LinguisticsPro-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont[range=it/{Greek,greek}]{LinguisticsPro-Italic.otf}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Greek,greek}]{LinguisticsPro-Bold.otf}
\setmathfont[range=bfit/{Greek,greek}]{LinguisticsPro-BoldItalic.otf}

\begin{document}
\( \symup{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\varepsilon\Alpha\Beta\Gamma abc ABC} \\
   \symit{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\varepsilon\Alpha\Beta\Gamma abc ABC} \\
   \symbfup{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\varepsilon\Alpha\Beta\Gamma abc ABC} \\
   \symbfit{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\varepsilon\Alpha\Beta\Gamma abc ABC}
 \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

In the samples above, the Greek letters are all from Linguistics Pro, and the Latin letters from TeX Gyre Pagella Math.  You might also see if you like the Greek letters from Asana Math or Palatino Linotype better; these are designed to match Palatino (and therefore its clone Pagella).  You can tell that Utopia is somewhat narrower.

This simple version has some quirks, such as `\varepsilon` but not `\epsilon` being available; it is possible to work around them, e.g. by tweaking the `range=` of `\setmathfont` or loading it again to get the missing Greek letters.  This also only sets up Greek math symbols.  You’d need to do more work to be able to write Greek words in the body text.